# How to install Pantheon on Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: 15.04, desktop-environments, pantheon

is it safe to install elementary OS DE Pantheon on Ubuntu 15.04 without doing any damage to the system? if so how?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
```

Update and install

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop
```

Thats it, now log out and on the login page, the Pantheon desktop should be visible in the list of desktop environments.

Comment: This answer is now obsolete, as the ppa no longer provides packages for 15.04

Answer (score 1):

Okay, for this answer, I'll follow the advice of [Guss](https://askubuntu.com/users/6537/guss) who managed to successfully install pantheon on Ubuntu 15.04.

- First of all, rebuild `ubuntu-extras-keyring` locally following these commands:

```
mkdir ubuntu-keyring && cd ubuntu-keyring
sudo apt-get install -y debhelper
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-extras-keyring/ubuntu-extras-keyring_2010.09.27.{tar.gz,dsc}
tar -xf *.tar.gz
cd ubuntu-extras-keyring-2010.09.17
debuild -i -us -uc -b
sudo dpkg -i ../ubuntu-extras-keyring_2010.09.27_all.deb
```

- Guss then goes on to mention: "After that, elementary-desktop will install, but will error out at the end because it depends on `systemd-shim` which is no longer needed nor wanted with 15.04 having a full SystemD implementation. 
  " --------- Once you get this error, do the following:

```
sudo dpkg --force-depends -r indicator-datetime
sudo apt-get purge unity-control-center unity-control-center-signon
```

Pantheon should now be installed on your system.

Comment: I am tempted to try what you've mentioned here, except it doesn't make straight sense. elementary-desktop will install from where? And where is the advice that Guss mentioned? (You just linked to his profile). And that last pair of commands... why would I want to run those?

Comment: I found his answer and only now realized that this question should be marked as a duplicate. I did not find the other question before.